# Scope of session objects in PKCS#11

Tags: pkcs#11

Assume we have 2 tokens: T1 and T2. S1 - session open with T1, S2 - session open with T2. All sessions logged in as user. S1 creates session object O1.
Can we access session object O1 via S2? That is can we access the session object created by session linked to different token then the token operating session linked to?

---

The question has raised from following place in cryptoki document: "...That is, if a single application has multiple sessions open with a token, and it uses one of
them to create a session object, then that session object is visible through any of THAT
application’s sessions..." THAT == multiple sessions open with a token ?

Comment: According to following text session objects visible to ALL application's sessions (with no regard to tokens): "...the access to a given session object which is shown in Table 6 is
limited to sessions belonging to the application which owns that object (i.e., which
created that object)..."

Answer (score 1):

I don' think you can access O1 (object that resides inside Token1) via S2 (session open with Token2).

For instance, let's assume an application connects to 2 different tokens and then creates 2 objects:

- An AES encryption key on Token 1
- A wrappable RSA private key on Token 2

Then, the application commands (on either session) to have the RSA key wrapped by AES key.
That's hardly possible because the two tokens are not aware of each other at all and won't allow that operation.

Comment: Please do not ask additional questions in comments, Kaponir. Letting your acceptance of an answer depend on additional questions is extremely rude.

Comment: Session objects can live in cryptoki dll in the same table (in my cryptoki library they are in process memory). The solution where to store session objects is implementation dependent. I consider the abstract PKCS#11 standard point of view. Thank you.